# arithmetic circuits for polynomials (updated)

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, arithmetic-circuits

I am concerned about the  following question, consider
$P_n(x)= \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{x^n}{n!}$

Is there a straight line program (or arithmetic circuits) of polynomial size (wrt $n$) for the  polynomial $P_{2^n}(x)$? The difficulty seems to lie in the factorial, as for example the polynomial $x^{2^n}$ has a polynomial size arithmetic circuit (by repeated squaring).

Sorry in my previous post I did not make the question clear, as it would become a very simple question.

Comment: 1) You might want to specify "constant-free straight line program," since otherwise a standard assumption is that constants are free. 2) What is your motivation? I could see this being a homework question, though I could also see this being a non-homework question.

Comment: yes, it is constant-free. Thanks for comments.

Comment: it is not a homework. The motivation is that if the answer is positive, loosely speaking one can evaluate $P_n(x)$ in a complexity class lower than Pspace for large $n$.

Comment: To make the question even clearer you could just define $P_n(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{2^n} x^i/i!$ in the first place, and point out that the summation goes all the way up to $2^n$.

Comment: Borwein's method for the factorial is the asymptotically best I am aware of http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20594/factoriality-testing-algorithms-and-their-efficiency/

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow The coefficients of the polynomial are not integers, therefore I do not know what it means for a circuit computing $P_n$ to be constant-free. Usually, constant-free circuits have no division... Of course it is not possible here to be constant-free and division-free!

Comment: Where in the world  is this homework? ;-)

Comment: @MarkusBläser: the original question was *much* simpler, which is what made me think it might've been homework.

Comment: @Bruno: I was thinking of constant-free circuits *with* division, so that the difficulty of computing the constants could still be taken into account, even though they're not all integers.

Comment: BTW it is not clear that allowing constants makes the problem easy. In fact in the Bürgisser paper Markus cited, constants and divisions are allowed.

Answer (score 7):

I assume that you mean $P_n(x)= \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{x^i}{i!}$.

Peter Bürgisser shows that if this problem is hard, then computing the permanent
is hard (http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00037-009-0260-x).
To my best knowledge, your problem is open.

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that "permanent is hard" here means "for constant and division free circuits".